# Bamboo trigger on JIRA update and vice versa

Tags: jira, integration, bamboo

I have to configure our Bamboo server to work with Jira. My Objective is to trigger the Bamboo build from JIRA (when issue update) and Build status of Bamboo update into Jira with respective issue.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just take a look into the official documentations; here the links:

[Running a Bamboo Build when Releasing a Version](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/running-a-bamboo-build-when-releasing-a-version-720412393.html)

[Viewing Bamboo activity in JIRA applications](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/viewing-bamboo-activity-in-jira-applications-399377384.html)